# Audio streaming and voice recording via HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, audio-recording, playback

I'm on a new project that requires to stream audio files (mp3) and record voice messages.. of course my first option was to use flash. But the problem is that the customer wants the website to be iPhone friendly.

Is there any technologie that allows me to play and record voice messages just with javascript/php/xhtml?

And of course, the website should be fully compatible with firefox, safari, internet explorer, etc.

I googled it and everything I found was flash-based.

but if you have any clue about it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to record sound you should do it with the new HTML5's api's, you can read more about it on
https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers

However, this is theory, in reality no browsers support it and there is no way to do it.  So in short: you cannot do what you ask.

What you could do is create an iPhone native app for those who want to use iPhone, and a flash website for those who want to access it with a regular browser.

Comment: That's a *proposed* HTML5 API, right? The linked page itself has title "beyond HTML5".

Comment: The HTML5 standard is not yet final, many of the things are just already implemented but still in proposal state... I think it will end up in the HTML5 standard, but only the future will tell...  so yes, it is a proposed api, but again, HTML5 is not yet final...

Comment: i think is too risky to develop something in html5 yet.. at least not for a customer.. have in mind that even xhtml and css2 has crossbrowser issues.. i can't even imagine how much i'm gonna digg into html5 to make it work... looks really nice, it will be really cool.. but so far.. i'm not buying it.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not even the new-ish HTML5 has any features to *record* audio. You'd need to go through Flash or Java - but that would rule out iPhone.